# Kafka connect - File Source

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

It seems connect file source is reading from the beginning of the files when the connector is restarted .
I couldn't find the equivalent configuration.

How to specify to read only the appended data ( Please note this only happens if connect is restarted , in that case, it is only reading the data that got appended) .

Comment: What is the value for `offset.flush.interval.ms` ? Is the file at `offset.storage.file.filename` present between restarts?

Comment: These are the values offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000